# Calling inet_pton through Cython

Tags: python, posix, ipv6, cython

I want to call inet_pton in Cython for IPv6 addresses. Basically I want to do the equivalent of the following C code:

```
char str[16];
inet_pton(AF_INET6, "12:212::122", &str);
```

I tried the following:

```
cdef char buff[16]
inet_pton(AF_INET6, address, &buff):
```

But this gives an error: "Taking address of non-lvalue".

What is the right way to do it? Finally I need to convert the IPv6 address string to python long.

Comment: Note you should be using `getnameinfo` and `getaddrinfo` as `inet_pton` and `inet_ntop` do not support IPv6 zones.

Answer (score 3):

Use `buff` or `&buff[0]` instead of `&buff`.